# Align wordpress site title with logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website tite is not aligned with the logo
This is how it looks now:
[image]

Wordpess is generating the following html snippet:

```
<div id="logo" class="clearfix">

    <a href="http://localhost/test/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/icon.png" class="custom-logo" alt="recette flocon advoine" itemprop="logo"></a>                     
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/test/" rel="home">test test</a></h1>



        <h2 class="site-description">slogan</h2>

    </div>
```

How can I get something like this : 
[image]

Comment: You've asked a CSS question without providing any of the CSS so it's difficult to tell what is going on.  I'd say try adding a 'vertical-align:middle;' to the image and/or text and see what happens.  Sometimes floats and inline-blocks don't align up quite right and that works.  If not, my recommendation would be just to add a top-margin on the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#logo{display: table;}
.h1{display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
```

This should work, if not, try:
top: 50%; margin-top: - half.the.height.of.the.font.size .
By the way, "http://localhost/test/" this is wrong on so many levels. Use "index.php / index.html" instead.

Answer (score 0):

To your h1 element add the following: `style="padding-top:20px;"` resulting:

```
<h1 class="site-title" style="padding-top:20px;>
```

Add more padding pixels as needed.